Script to move row to new sheet started to timeout
I use a third-party form to add entries to a Google Sheet tab titled "Inbox." I added a script on a time-based trigger to...

Check if column J contains "Y"
If yes, move the row to a new sheet titled "Completed"
Delete the row from "Inbox"
Add a new blank row to "Inbox"

Everything was working fine, but recently started receiving timeout errors.  This usually occurs when the Inbox starts to fill up with entries.  I'm attaching a copy of the GS.
text
Script
function doneCopy() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Inbox");
  var values = sheet.getRange(1, 10, sheet.getLastRow(), 1).getValues();
  var moveRows = values.reduce(function(ar, e, i) {
    if (e[0] == "Y") ar.push(i + 1);
    return ar;
  }, []);
  var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Completed");
  moveRows.forEach(function(e) {
    sheet.getRange(e, 1, 1, sheet.getLastColumn()).copyTo(targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1),{contentsOnly:true});
      sheet.insertRowsAfter(sheet.getMaxRows(), 1);

  });
  moveRows.reverse().forEach(function(e) {sheet.deleteRow(e)});

}

I'm wondering if there is something in my script that is slowing the run down.  I'm hoping someone might have a suggestion or solution.  Thank you.

The problem you are experiencing is that you are making a lot of separate calls to the Google Sheets service, which is causing the execution time to exceed the maximum allowed time.
My suggestion for creating the code more efficiently and probably avoid the timeout errors message.
Code change:
function doneCopy() {


var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Inbox");
  var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();
  var lastColumn = sheet.getLastColumn();
  var values = sheet.getRange(1, 10, lastRow, 1).getValues();
  var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Completed");
  var targetLastRow = targetSheet.getLastRow();
  
  var rowsToMove = [];
  var rowsToDelete = [];
  
  for(var i=0; i<values.length; i++){
    if(values[i][0] == "Y"){
      rowsToMove.push(sheet.getRange(i+1, 1, 1, lastColumn).getValues());
      rowsToDelete.push(i+1);
    }
  }
  
  if(rowsToMove.length > 0){
    targetSheet.getRange(targetLastRow + 1, 1, rowsToMove.length, lastColumn).setValues([].concat.apply([], rowsToMove));
  }
  
  for(var i=rowsToDelete.length-1; i>=0; i--){
    sheet.deleteRow(rowsToDelete[i]);
  }

This code reduces the number of calls to the Google Sheets service by batching the operations. It first collects all the rows that need to be moved and deleted, then it moves all the rows at once and finally deletes all the rows at once. This should significantly reduce the execution time of your script.
